# PHP sum array values if a specific column has a duplicate value

Tags: php

i have an array. i want to check if there is duplicate FEE and if there is i want to sum up all the values with the same FEE COLUMN.

```
[12] => Array
    (
        [type] => Other Miscellaneous Fees
        [fee] => 158
        [amount] => -22.56
        [code] => COL_AUDIO
        [feedesc] => COLLEGE AUDIO VISUAL FEE
    )

[13] => Array
    (
        [type] => Other Miscellaneous Fees
        [fee] => 158
        [amount] => -297.86
        [code] => COL_AUDIO
        [feedesc] => COLLEGE AUDIO VISUAL FEE
    )

[14] => Array
    (
        [type] => Other Miscellaneous Fees
        [fee] => 182
        [amount] => -40.00
        [code] => STRAP
        [feedesc] => ID STRAP
    )

[15] => Array
    (
        [type] => Other Miscellaneous Fees
        [fee] => 177
        [amount] => -105.00
        [code] => PRISAA
        [feedesc] => PRISAA
    )
```

desired output, i want it to store in a new array. ive tried playing with array_sum and array colum. but it will sum all the fields. thanks

```
array_sum(array_column($feesArray, 'fee')); 

  [0] => Array
    (
        [type] => Other Miscellaneous Fees
        [fee] => 158
        [amount] => -320.42
        [code] => COL_AUDIO
        [feedesc] => COLLEGE AUDIO VISUAL FEE
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [type] => Other Miscellaneous Fees
        [fee] => 182
        [amount] => -40.00
        [code] => STRAP
        [feedesc] => ID STRAP
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [type] => Other Miscellaneous Fees
        [fee] => 177
        [amount] => -105.00
        [code] => PRISAA
        [feedesc] => PRISAA
    )
```

Comment: You probably don't want to "sum" up the elements, but get rid of elements with non unique fee. This is a basic manipulation which you should be able to do with a simple array regeneration with an if and a "master" array of "used" fees.

Comment: I have closed this page using another page with a superior answer.  I wouldn't recommend the accepted answer to anyone, so at some point it would be better for researchers if this page did not exist.  Separately, I have downvoted the question because there is no proof of effort, research, or even a broken coding attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To SUM up all the values with the same FEE COLUMN you can create a for loop that iterates each result to check if the value is already in the array.

```
$data = Array(
    Array
    (
        "type" => "Other Miscellaneous Fees",
        "fee" => 158,
        "amount" => -22.56,
        "code" => "COL_AUDIO",
        "feedesc" => "COLLEGE AUDIO VISUAL FEE"
    ),
    Array(
        "type" => "Other Miscellaneous Fees",
        "fee" => 158,
        "amount" => -297.86,
        "code" => "COL_AUDIO",
        "feedesc" => "COLLEGE AUDIO VISUAL FEE"
    ),
    Array
    (
        "type" => "Other Miscellaneous Fees",
        "fee" => 182,
        "amount" => -40.00,
        "code" => "STRAP",
        "feedesc" => "ID STRAP"
    ),
    Array
    (
        "type" => "Other Miscellaneous Fees",
        "fee" => 177,
        "amount" => -105.00,
        "code" => "PRISAA",
        "feedesc" => "PRISAA"
    )
);


foreach ($data as $data_key => &$data_searcher) {
    foreach ($data as $data_searcher_key => $data_searcher_value) {
        if(
            ($data_searcher['fee'] === $data_searcher_value['fee']) &&
            $data_key !== $data_searcher_key
        ){
            $data_searcher['amount'] += $data_searcher_value['amount'];
            unset($data[$data_searcher_key]);
        }
    }
}


echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: how can i store this to a new array to restart the index of each item?

Comment: Not sure i understand what you are asking

Comment: why its only adding the first duplicate value in the array, the other values will not be sum up

Comment: I just ran a test, you are incorrect. The above code will combine all Array items by the FEE key field and add the amounts together.

Comment: i've tried to copy the last two elements in the array and run it but the output is not what im expecting? can you try it. its not working for me